# Is there a candidate for a post-quantum one-way group action?

Tags: cr.crypto-security, quantum-computing, gr.group-theory

Is there a known family of [group actions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action#Definition) with a designated element

in the set that is being acted on, where it is known how to efficiently

$\:$ sample (essentially uniformly) from the groups, compute the inverse operations,

$\:$ compute the group operations, and compute the group actions

and there is no known efficient quantum algorithm

for succeeding with non-negligible probability in

$\:$ given as inputs the index of a group action and the result of

$\:$ a sampled group element acting on the designated element,

$\:$ find a group element whose action on the designated element is the second input

?

As far as I am aware, those provide the only known constructions of non-interactive statistically hiding commitments in which knowledge of a trapdoor enables efficient and undetectable equivocation, a property that is useful for zero knowledge protocols and adaptive security.

Any family of one-way group homomorphisms with the first three properties (from the third and fourth lines of this post) can be converted into such a thing by having the domains act on the codomains via $\: \langle a,b\rangle \mapsto h(a)\cdot b \:$, $\:$ with the identity elements as the distinguished elements.

A restricted version of the [Pedersen commitment scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commitment_scheme#A_perfectly_binding_scheme_based_on_the_discrete_log_problem) can be obtained as a special case of applying the above conversion to the group exponential homomorphism, whose one-wayness is equivalent to the hardness of the discrete logarithm problem, although that is not hard for quantum algorithms.  (See [Shor's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shor%27s_algorithm#Discrete_logarithms) and that page's section on discrete logarithm.)

Answer (score 4):

**Yes**, there is an old proposal for this due to [Couveignes](https://ia.cr/2006/291), which was independently rediscovered by [Rostovtsev and Stolbunov](https://ia.cr/2006/145).

In both cases, the set of elliptic curves with some common endomorphism ring $\mathcal O$ is acted on by the ideal class group of $\mathcal O$. The secret key is essentially a description of an isogeny via its kernel ideal, and the action of a group element $[\mathfrak a]$ takes a curve $E$ to the codomain of said isogeny:
$$
    ([\mathfrak a], E) \longmapsto E/\mathfrak a = E/\bigcap_{\alpha\in\mathfrak a}\ker\alpha
    \text.
$$
There is a nice graph-walking interpretation of this action, which is described (for instance) in Section 14.1 of [Luca De Feo's lecture notes](https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.04062). <sub><sup>(They also contain more of the background necessary to understand this construction!)</sup></sub>

While it is possible to invert the group action by solving an instance of the hidden-shift problem, giving rise to a [subexponential quantum attack](https://arxiv.org/abs/1012.4019), the system remains unbroken for reasonably big parameter sizes.
A much bigger problem is that these schemes are painfully slow in practice: Even after considerable [optimization effort](https://ia.cr/2018/485), one computation of the group action still takes *minutes*.

The performance issue has been tackled by a recent proposal called [CSIDH](https://ia.cr/2018/383) by switching to supersingular elliptic curves, which drastically improves efficiency while keeping essentially the same underlying structure. It is still slow relative to comparable pre-quantum schemes, as well as incomparable post-quantum schemes, but may have a place in a post-quantum world due to its unique features.